# Is there a way to emit event inside directive

Tags: javascript, angular, events, angular2-directives, angular2-components

I use Angular2 and write some @Directive with drag and drop (in some bounded area) and want to emit event when dragging is end - so when dragging is end I invoke method endDragging. 1. how body of this method should look like?,  2. how usage of this directive should look like (especially how to set eventHandler to directive).

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[draggable]'
})
export class Draggable {
    @Input('draggable') boundary: any;
    ...
    endDraging() {
        // ??? how emit event from here?
    }
}
```

In html template (???=how set handler for draggable-endDragging event):

```
<div [draggable]="{x_min:10, x_max:100, y_min:20, y_max:200}" ...???... >
...some content...
</div>
```

Comment: what type of event your want to emit from here ?

Comment: event that user stop draging element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define service with global event and use it in directive

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
export class GlobalEventService {

    private eventSubject = new ReplaySubject<string>(1);

    constructor() { }

    public getEventObservable() {
        return this.eventSubject.asObservable();
    }

    public emitEvent(message) {
        this.eventSubject.next(message);
    }
}
```

Code is out of head and may contain bugs. From outside someone in service do

```
globalEventService.getEventObservable().subscribe(message => { … })
```

while directive use this servis sending event like this

```
globalEventService.emitEvent('some messsage')
```

Answer (score 1):

I found some working solution but unfortunatly is a little bit dirty workaround:

Let say we have component which use draggable div in his template:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'my-component',
    templateUrl: './my-component.html',
    directives: [ Draggable ],
})
export class MyComponent {

    myVariable = 0;    

    boundary() {
        return {
            x_min:10, 
            x_max:100, 
            y_min:20, 
            y_max:200,
            self: this, 
            onDragEnd: this.onDragEnd,
        };
    }

    onDragEnd(x,y,boundary) {
       // handle drag end event, to get acces to 'this' (instance of MyComponent class use boundary.self)
       boundary.self.myVariable = 1;
    }

}
```

In template .html we have:

```
<div [draggable]="boundary()">...</div>
```

And out directive will look like that:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[draggable]'
})
export class Draggable {
    @Input('draggable') boundary: any;
    ...
    endDraging() {
        this.boundary.onDragEnd(this.x,this.y, this.boundary);
    }
}
```

The dirty thing is that MyComponent.onDragEnd method don't have access to 'this'(!!!) so I must put "this" in 'self' in object retuned by boundary() method. I don't know what is the reason - may be angular causes that, or may be typescript causes that problem... i don't know.

UPDATE:

I think that if we change line `onDragEnd: this.onDragEnd,` in `MyComponent` to

```js
onDragEnd: (x,y,boundary) => this.onDragEnd(x,y,boundary),
```

then we will have normal access to `this` inside `onDragEnd` and solution actually will be not "dirty".